# knockoutjs foreach not working in Wijmo modal dialog

Tags: knockout.js, wijmo

I have created a modal dialog with wijmo. Inside the dialog I want to display content which depends on a knockoutjs model.

```
<tr data-bind="visible:fields().length > 0">
    <td>Enter</td>
    <td>
        <div data-bind="foreach:fields">
            <span data-bind="text:$data"></span>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The condition(`visible:fields().length > 0`) works as expected and "Enter" will be displayed if I anything is added to the observable collection. But the span(s) of the foreach will never show up.

I have created the following http://jsfiddle.net/79uh3/ which demonstrates the problem.

If the div that binds the wijdialog is commented out, the example works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a strange behaviour. Single solution that I found is to add default value to `observable array`

```
var VM = {
    fields: ko.observableArray([""]),
    newField: ko.observable(),
    addItem: function(){
        this.fields.push(this.newField());
    }
};
```

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yy35P/)

Comment: Yes this works for some strange reason, but does not lead to a correct behavior since now `Enter` is visible, even if there are is no 'real data' in the `observable array`. What I also did not notice before is the fact that the `addItem` event is triggered twice (at least with Chrome 27 on Windows)

Comment: @gtroxler I can propose only this variant http://jsfiddle.net/yy35P/. But it has workaround like in my answer